# setting image from decoded base64 crash my app

Tags: android

I dont know how to look at logcat , im new. heres the my code for displaying record from mysqldatabase. i can fetch the blob file from database and display it on textview as text which determine that theres nothing wrong on getting data from database, the problem is after i decoded it and display on imageview, my app crash

```
private void showUsers(String json){
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
        JSONArray result =  jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.TAG_JSON_ARRAY);
        JSONObject c = result.getJSONObject(0);
        String username = c.getString(Config.TAG_UNAME);
        String password = c.getString(Config.TAG_PWORD);
        String firstname = c.getString(Config.TAG_FNAME);
        String lastname = c.getString(Config.TAG_LNAME);
        String birthday = c.getString(Config.TAG_BDAY);
        String gender = c.getString(Config.TAG_GENDER);
        String image = c.getString(Config.TAG_IMAGE);


        editTextUName.setText(username);
        editTextPWord.setText(password);
        editTextFName.setText(firstname);
        editTextLName.setText(lastname);
        tvbirthday.setText(birthday);

        if (gender.equals("Male")){
            radiomale.setChecked(true);
        }
        if (gender.equals("Female")){
            radiofemale.setChecked(true);
        }
        // i can set the base64 to text
        //    tvblob.setText(image);

        byte[] kahitano = Base64.decode(image,Base64.DEFAULT);
        Bitmap decodeimage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(kahitano,0,kahitano.length);
        imageblob.setImageBitmap(decodeimage);



    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You use this method that i'm using in my app decode Base64 String Bitmap

```
public static Bitmap decodeBase64ToBitmap(String input) {
    byte[] decodedByte = Base64.decode(input, 0);
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedByte, 0, decodedByte.length);
}
```

Comment: where should i put that code?  i know theres something wrong on my decoding,

Comment: copy full code add outside your `showUsers` function

Comment: ok thanks, sorry my skills are very low, i dont have an idea, my blob string is stored on the "image" string, snd that said string is inside the show user function,  guide me pls

Comment: its still crashing, help me